# Delete Button doesn't work properly any more after "Convert Form's Macros to Visual Basic" was executed

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've created two tables

Languages:
    `IDLanguage Language
      1      English
      2      German
      3      French
      4      Polish
      5      Italian`

Greetings:
    `IDGreeting  Greeting       IDLanguage_FK
      1      Good Morning       1
      2      Guten Morgen       2
      3      Bonjour            3`

Both tables are connected by the foreign key `IDLanguage_FK` with the option *Enforce Referential Integrity*. So the languages Polish and Italian of the table *languages* has no counterpart in the table *greetings*.

I've created a form bounded to the *languages* table with a list box showing all languages and a delete button. Both object elements were created with the Control Wizard.

If I want to delete the language Polish or Italian there won't be a problem. If I want to delete one of the first three languages, an error message pops up, indicating that the record includes related records in the *greetings* table. Everything fine so far.

Converting the form's macro to Visual Basic causes now problems with the delete button. After the conversion, it's still possible to delete the two non-related languages. But if I try to delete one of the three related languages, then no error message pops up.

The converted VBA code for the delete button looks like the following:

```
Private Sub Button_Delete_Click()

On Error GoTo Button_Delete_Click_Err
On Error Resume Next

DoCmd.GoToControl Screen.PreviousControl.Name
Err.Clear

If (Not Form.NewRecord) Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
End If
If (Form.NewRecord And Not Form.Dirty) Then
    Beep
End If
If (Form.NewRecord And Form.Dirty) Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
End If
If (MacroError <> 0) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
End If

DoCmd.RefreshRecord
    Button_Delete_Click_Exit:
       Exit Sub
    Button_Delete_Click_Err:
       MsgBox Error$
       Resume Button_Delete_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

Has anyone faced the same problem, that the error message won't pop up after conversion. For my purposes it's vital to show the user this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, that generated code is a mess (sorry).

You don't get an error message, because it all runs after `On Error Resume Next`, which ignores all errors.

I suggest you start simple with this, and add special cases as needed:

```vb
Private Sub Button_Delete_Click()

On Error GoTo Button_Delete_Click_Err

    If (Not Form.NewRecord) Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
    End If

Button_Delete_Click_Exit:
   Exit Sub
Button_Delete_Click_Err:
   MsgBox Error$
   Resume Button_Delete_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Starting with a clearer code makes everything easier.